# Unable to create non-standard object properties using Facebook Object API

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook Object API to create Facebook Objects and then list them. 
[Based on the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#creatinguser) we should be able to store non-standard object properties in 'data' field, for example, calories value for a food object, or elevation height for a mountain object.

But when I am trying to create the objects, I couldn't see the 'data' fields in either object browser, graph api explorer or in the response of objects listing.

Is it a bug?

How I create an object (Method 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object.provisionedForPost = YES;
object[@"type"] = @"mangasendalpha:Template";
object[@"title"] = @"another one!";
object[@"image"] = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Enchiladas_suizas.jpg/800px-Enchiladas_suizas.jpg";
object[@"url"] = @"https://url.com";

NSDictionary *data = @{@"keyword":@"haha"};
object[@"data"] = data;

[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if(error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"Success %@", result);
                                       [self tryList];
                                   }
                               }];
```

create an object (Method 2):

```
NSString *type = @"mangasendalpha:Template";
NSString *title = @"hei hei can you see the data?";
NSString *imageUri = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Enchiladas_suizas.jpg/800px-Enchiladas_suizas.jpg";
NSString *url = @"http://www.url.com";
NSString *description = @"a new template description";
NSDictionary *objectProperties = @{@"keyword":@"hehe"};

FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForPostOpenGraphObjectWithType:type title:title image:imageUri url:url description:description objectProperties:objectProperties];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
    {
        LogError(@"%@",error);
    }
    else
    {
        Log(@"success:%@", result);
        [self tryList];
    }
}];
[connection start];
```

Regardless of how I create the objects, I can see the title, images, etc. correctly except the data field that should says "keywords = haha".

This is an example of the response from graph api explorer:

```
    {
      "id": "106170429585804", 
      "url": "http://www.url.com/", 
      "type": "mangasendalpha:template", 
      "title": "hei hei can you see the data?", 
      "image": [
        {
          "url": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Enchiladas_suizas.jpg/800px-Enchiladas_suizas.jpg"
        }
      ], 
      "description": "a new template description", 
      "updated_time": "2013-04-25T16:55:48+0000", 
      "created_time": "2013-01-09T05:51:44+0000", 
      "application": {
        "id": "512497238785794", 
        "name": "MangaSendAlpha", 
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=512497238785794"
      }, 
      "is_scraped": false, 
      "post_action_id": 524865977555471
    }
```

If I try to list the objects, explicitly saying I want id, image and DATA:

```
- (void) tryList
{
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/objects/mangasendalpha:Template?fields=id,image,data"];
NSDictionary *parameters = nil;
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:path parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *response,
   NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         Log(@"response: %@", response);
     }
     else
     {
         Log(@"has error: %@", error);
     }
 }];
}
```

This is what I will get:

```
data =     (
            {
        id = 106170429585804;
        image =             (
                            {
                url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Enchiladas_suizas.jpg/800px-Enchiladas_suizas.jpg";
            }
        );
    },
            {
        id = 386877688092664;
        image =             (
                            {
                url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Enchiladas_suizas.jpg/800px-Enchiladas_suizas.jpg";
            }
        );
    },...
```

WHERE IS THE DATA FIELD?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I just figured out myself.
Your custom property need to be predefined in the facebook app settings page.

1. Go to developers.facebook.com/apps/your app
2. On the left hand side, choose Open Graph -> Types -> choose the object type you are interested,
3. You will see a list of object properties. and there is a magical "add property" button there!

Once you have added the "Custom" property, object API can now create a new object with that property correctly.